# How strings are compared to each other?

Tags: java, string, comparison

When comparing 2 strings, what does actually happen? How do we determine that *content* inside a String A is equal to String B? Do we look in unicode character table for element to element comparision of both Strings? if yes, then how does equals() know about element in a String like "ABC", how does equal() sperates A from BC to compare it to first element of other string ?

Comment: The compiler has no idea. The equals() method of the String class does that, at runtime. Not the compiler. The compiler transforms source code into bytecode. It doesn't execute the code.

Comment: @JBNizet okay, but how does it do that? I looked at equals(), i dont actually understand it.

Comment: Well, post the code you looked at (it varies depending on the Java version), and tell us what you don't understand in that code. But basically, it compares the length of both strings, and then compare the characters, one by one.

Comment: FYI, link to [source code of `String`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/75aa2a8e7304/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) in OpenJDK for Java 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are basically immutable wrappers around a `char[]`, with a lot of useful utility methods.

So, to check if two strings are equal, you simply check if they both have `char` arrays of equal size and with equal content.

Using the [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class, which has useful methods for working with arrays, a simplified `String` implementation might look like this:

```
public final class String {
    private char[] value;

    public String(char[] value) {
        this.value = value.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (! (obj instanceof String))
            return false;
        String other = (String) obj;
        return Arrays.equals(this.value, other.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(this.value);
    }

    public char[] toCharArray() {
        return this.value.clone();
    }

    public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(this.value, beginIndex, endIndex));
    }

    // more utility methods

}
```

The real `String` class is more complicated, in different ways depending on the Java version.

E.g. in earlier versions, the `char[]` could be shared by multiple `String` objects, so e.g. `substring()` wouldn't need to copy the array.

In later versions, optimizations have changed to store characters in `byte` *([LATIN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1))* arrays if possible, instead of `char` *([UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16))* arrays, in order to save space.

These various optimizations will of course complicate the internal code of the `String` utility methods, which might be what is confusing you when you look at the JDK source code.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated note: the sharing of a single char[] was actually a premature optimization.  They thought it would optimize some String operations to share the same array and specify a start and end point so string.substring wouldn't create an entirely new string but they didn't take into consideration the idea that web developers would download an entire web page and split/filter out a few words, expecting the original string to be collected.   Removing the shared backing array was more of a de-optimization :)

Answer (score 1):

When in Doubt always check the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that
>   represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

When you use equals with Strings this is actually happens

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So it will return only if you are comparing other String if you have the same sequence because it is comparing Characters.